# Using MySQL to prepend product names from a specific product category

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce I would like to add a few characters to the product name, so they match with a client's QB SKU.

The products in question are all part of the same product category. I'm hoping there's a mySql query/command I can tweak to do something like this pathetic pseudocode:

in table wp_posts where category = "a product category" PREPEND "abc_" to product name.

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: it also seems that the categories are not indicated in the wp_posts table... which ... is confusing lol.

Comment: Say if you have a product `ProA` which belongs to `Cat1` then it should be rename to `Cat1-ProA`? and what if the product belongs to multiple category. say `ProB` belongs to `Cat1` and `Cat2` then what will be the Product Name for this case?

Comment: What I want is to add, for example, "abc_" to the product_name for all products with the catergory, for example "xyz"  products belonging to multiple categories are inconsequential because I'm changing based on a single category... the products name will change but the category/categories will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:** I am not an SQL expert, but it will certainly help you to understand how to build your complete SQL query.

> At the end below, you will find a custom function that you will run one time, that will do the job.

1. Get your product category ID …
2. in "wp_term_taxonomy" table check the corresponding 'term_taxonomy_id' (in general the same as the product category ID).

Here is the way to get an array of the product IDs for this specific category:

```
global $wpdb;

// Define HERE the corresponding 'term_taxonomy_id' of your product category.
$term_taxonomy_id = 11;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships";
$product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT object_id  
    FROM $table_name 
    WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = $term_taxonomy_id 
    ORDER BY $table_name.object_id ASC
" );
```

Tested and works

---

With that code you can make a function that is going to achieve what you want to do:

```
function prepending_products_names(){

    global $wpdb;

    // Define HERE the corresponding 'term_taxonomy_id' of your product category.
    $term_taxonomy_id = 11;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships";
    $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT object_id
        FROM $table_name
        WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = $term_taxonomy_id
        ORDER BY $table_name.object_id ASC
    " );

    foreach( $product_ids as $product_id ){
        // get the post object
        $post_obj = get_post($product_id);
        // get the product sku
        $product_sku = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_sku', true);
        // Customizing the product name
        // (You can prepend the a part of the sku to it)
        $custom_product_name = 'abc_'. $post_obj->post_title;

        // Updating the product name
        wp_update_post( array(
            'id' => $product_id,
            'post_title' => $custom_product_name,
        ) );
    }
}

// Run this one time reloading a backend page and comment it 
// (or remove the code aftewards).

if(is_admin())
    prepending_products_names();
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Comment: LoicTheAztec - will this update the actual database? and i leave it in the function.php for good?

Comment: @BrockVond Yes my function will update the database: wp_update_post() WordPress function. But make a database backup or a backup of post table **before**… This way you can test it safely. After usage (one time) remove it. This function will run when a page of your site will be browsed (so be careful)… you could add a conditional with is_admin() to run it from the backend (more secure)…

Comment: ok so this code, if left in function.php would continue to add a prefix to the items over and over again if i don't remove it after the first run?  where would the is_admin() go on this?  I am the admin and would only want it to run (even once) from the backend.  thanks again for all your help... i will test this today/tonight.

Comment: Ok I will try to contact you uh... within the next 2 hours or so (I'm at work for a bit)  Thanks @LoicTheAztec! Much Appreciated.

Comment: I will also select this as the right answer as SOON as I can test it out... few hours... sorry... DayJob interfering with SideJob.

Answer (score 1):

You do like this to get current product category ID

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $category_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}
```

Then use this to set the value based on product category.

```
if ($category_id == "1"){
        $sku = "your_value_if_current_cat_id_is_2";
}elseif ($category_id == "2"){
        $sku = "your_value_if_current_cat_id_is_2";
}else{
        $sku = "your_value_for_all_other_categories";
}
```

Now let's put this together and hook a function to replace your current title with the a new title appended with you chosen value for variable `$sku`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 ); 
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_my_single_title',5);

function woocommerce_my_single_title() { 

global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $category_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}

if ($category_id == "1"){
        $sku = "your_value_if_current_cat_id_is_2";
}elseif ($category_id == "2"){
        $sku = "your_value_if_current_cat_id_is_2";
}else{
        $sku = "your_value_for_all_other_categories";
}
        ?>
             <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>-<h2><?php echo $sku; ?></h2>
        <?php
     }
```

put the function in your functions.php file

Comment: awesome answer but I'm looking to prepend, not replace the SKU/Product Name.  Thanks tho.

Comment: @BrockVond This is not replacing, it's will append SKU to product name, and once you remove this code, it will go back as it was.